# Format a table style " ", receiving variable not defined error code

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I'm just getting started with VBA (like two days ago just getting started), so I'm sure this is a super easy fix that I'm just not smart enough to figure out.

I'm using the code below to create a table that will grow as new rows of data are added, but I don't want it to have a style (except black borders, but I can figure that part out later?). Whenever I try to run it, I get a "Variable Not Defined" error code referencing the last line. Please help?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Projections()

' Insert Table

Dim tbl As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set tbl = Range("A4").CurrentRegion
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=tbl).Name = "Projections"

ws.ListObjects(“Projections”).TableStyle = " "

End Sub
```

Comment: watch out for the smart quotes btw. You want " ". Avoid using Activesheet and use an explicit named sheet reference and then check that a table has been created with the desired name within that sheet. When you write _Range("A4").CurrentRegion_ you are also implicitly referencing the Activesheet (which ever happens to be active at the time)

Comment: Hi Elena, welcome!  Do you have an example of your data and the expected result please?  Also have you tried `tables` in excel, they dynamically grow in excel without the need of VBA.